# How to use transition with timer in d3?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to animate (with transition) an item entering a realtime chart.

As you can see, when the "Add circle" button is clicked, the circle stays at the bottom of the chart, and not animating upwards.

Interestingly, adding `.ease(d3.easeLinear)` to the transition solves the issue.

Why?

Is it conceptually wrong to use transition with timer in d3?

```js
const width = 300;
const height = 100;
const margin = { top: 0, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 50 };

const main = d3.select('.chart')
  .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

const now = Date.now();
const xScale = d3.scaleTime().domain([now - 10000, now]).range([0, width]);
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(5);

const xAxisG = main.append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(xAxis);

let data = [];

function drawCircles() {
  const t = d3.transition().duration(1000); //.ease(d3.easeLinear);
  const update = main.selectAll('circle').data(data);
  
  update.enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('r', d => d.value)
    .merge(update)
      .attr('cx', d => xScale(d.timestamp))
      .attr('cy', height)
      .transition(t)
      .attr('cy', height / 2);
}

d3.timer(() => {
  const now = Date.now();

  xScale.domain([now - 10000, now]);
  xAxisG.call(xAxis);
  
  drawCircles();
});

d3.select('.add-circle').on('click', () => {
  data.push({
    timestamp: Date.now() - 3000,
    value: 10
  });
});
```

```css
svg {
  margin: 30px;
}
.add-circle {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@4.4.1/build/d3.js"></script>
<button class="add-circle">Add circle</button>
<div class="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not the lack of an [easing](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/README.md#transition_ease). The problem is most probably the mix of `d3.timer` and `selection.transition`.

Let's see it step by step. You said that this:

```
const t = d3.transition().duration(1000);
```

Doesn't work, while this:

```
const t = d3.transition().duration(1000).ease(d3.easeLinear);
```

Works. Well, that's not the fact: it's not working. Whoever uses `easeLinear` can easily see that this is not a linear transition! Something funny is happening here...

Now, let's change the easing. The default easing (i.e., if you don't set any) is `easeCubic`. Therefore, if we do this:

```
const t = d3.transition().duration(1000).ease(d3.easeCubic);
```

It will have the same effect of your first code, without `ease`. Thus, it's not the fact that we set an `ease` that made the transition happen.

I tested all easings with your code, and some of them "worked", like `easeLinear` or `easeCircle`. The *worked* here is between quotes because the transition was **not** the normal one, the expected one. Some of them, like `easeCubic`, had no effect at all.

And that's because you can't mix `d3.timer` with transitions. I didn't have the chance to have a look at the source code, but most probably they use the same methods (like `requestAnimationFrame()` perhaps) and are conflicting.

**Solution**: move the transition to outside the function called by your `d3.timer`.

There are different ways for implementing that proposed solution (different coders will create different alternatives), but this is mine. First, we define a transitioning function:

```
function transitioning(elem) {
    const t = d3.transition().duration(1000).ease(d3.easeCubic);
    d3.select(elem)
        .transition(t)
        .attr('cy', height / 2);
}
```

And then, inside your function `drawCircles`, we call `transitioning` for each circle. However, we have to set a flag, so we don't call the `transitioning` function again and again to the same element:

```
function drawCircles() {

    const update = main.selectAll('circle').data(data);

    update.enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('r', d => d.value)
        .attr('cy', height)
        .attr("flag", 0)
        .merge(update)
        .attr('cx', d => xScale(d.timestamp))
        .each(function() {
            if (!(+d3.select(this).attr("flag"))) {
                transitioning(this)
            }
            d3.select(this).attr("flag", 1);
        });
}
```

And this is your updated CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLyXma?editors=0010

In the above CodePen, I'm using `easeCubic`. But you can see, in this other Pen, that it works without setting any easing: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/apwLxR?editors=0010

Comment: @Misha, Gerardo: Big brother is watching us ;-) Have a look at Mike Bostock's Block [*I Make Circles*](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/ad550c9d6d156ac726b45f48fa6ff2c7) , which does not exactly answer *this* question, but seems oddly related...

Comment: Mike created this example as a response to: https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/issues/65

Comment: *"Thanks Mike, this is much more helpful than the previous response"*. I only hope you're talking about *his* previous response...

Comment: Yes, 100%. I really appreciate your helpful answers Geraldo!